# Python: 'int' object is not subscriptable (pseudorandom generator)

Tags: python

I'm trying to create the Middle square pseaudorandom number generator (it basically takes an input, gets the number in the middle of the input and squares it, ie: 1234 -> 23^2)

This is my code and I get 'int' object is not subscriptable error on line 6:

```
middle = 0

def get_middle():
    x = 1
    y = int(input('type a number: '))
    middle = str(y[x:y-2])
    return middle

get_middle()
result = middle * middle
print(result)
```

I try to get the length of the number at slice out the middle.

Comment: Can you define `number in the middle`?

Comment: why are you hard coding x to 1? what if the number has 6 digits? You seem to be just taking every number from the first to the second last

Comment: He always wants to ignore the first character, but clearly that could be done with the number 1 itself.

Comment: Also, y-2 is probably not what you want.  In your example, y - 2 = 1232.  I'm not sure how that's useful at all.

Answer (score 2):

Don't turn it into a number if you're going to turn around and treat it as a string. Or at least, keep the string around, too.

```
strval = input('type a number: ')
intval = int(strval)
middle = strval[x:intval-2]
return int(middle)
```

Answer (score 0):

You use `y` as both a `str` for slicing, and an `int` for subtraction, you should use two separate variables.

```
x = 1
val = input('type a number: ')
y = int(val)
middle = val[x:y-2])
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what you mean by "`number in the middle`", I'll just assume you want to cut off the first and last characters.  Now, if you really want just the very middle digit, or 2 digits in the case of an even length, it would look more like the second function.

```
def get_middle(input_string):
    middle = input_string[1:-1]
    return int(middle)

def get_very_middle(input_string):
    if len(input_string) % 2 == 0:
        index = int(len(input_string) // 2)
    else:
        index = int(len(input_string) // 2) + 1
    middle = input_string[index-1:-(index-1)]
    return int(middle)

y = "0"
while len(y) < 3:
    y = input('type a number, with more than 3 digits: ')
    inty = int(y)


middle = get_middle(y)
print(middle)
result = middle * middle
print(result)
print("The very middle:")
middle = get_very_middle(y)
print(middle)
result = middle * middle
print(result)
```

I print out the middle number as well, so you can see exactly what you are squaring.